# angucomplete in a form

Tags: angularjs, forms

Can I make angucomplete item in an html form? (in angular.js of course)
What do I need to put in `selectedobject`?

Tried this code but it doesn't do what I need of course:

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="AddShareForm" novalidate ng-controller="AddArticleShareCtrl" ng-submit="AddShareForm.$valid && submit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="share-nick" class="col-xs-2 col-xl-2 control-label">User Nick</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xl-10">
                <angucomplete id="share-nick"
                              placeholder="User Nickname"
                              pause="100"
                              selectedobject="nick"
                              localdata="users"
                              searchfields="nick"
                              titlefield="nick"
                              minlength="1"
                              inputclass="form-control form-control-small"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="share-content" class="col-xs-2 col-xl-2 control-label">Share content message</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xl-10">
                <input type="text" placeholder="content" id="share-content" ng-model="AddShareForm.content">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xl-offset-2 col-xl-10">
                <button class="blue-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify ng-model.
http://plnkr.co/edit/q65Uyl?p=preview

Just to make it clear, I added a submit function:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  alert('About to submit [' + $scope.content + '] as ' + $scope.nick.title);
}
```

And also attached the nick name to message field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="share-content" class="col-xs-2 col-xl-2 control-label">Share content message</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xl-10">
        <input type="text" placeholder="content" id="share-content" ng-model="content"> by <span>{{nick.title}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want more features, try angucomplete-alt http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/

Comment: yeah... that's waht I ended up doing (I skipped the form and did it straight forward which has disadvantages).
Also already switched to angucomplete-alt because of bugs you fixed in alt! Thanks @ghiden

Answer (score 1):

After working off on this for some good length of time, I figured an excellent working solution to [anguautocomplete](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt)

In short answer, `selected-object` could be used as an "object", that you could use against the `title-field` attribute to specify which implies

```
$scope.selectedObjectName.titleFieldValue
```

Alternatively, `selected-object` could also be used as callback function as below, for reference, i will also post HTML side of this before to keep-up with JS.

```
<div angucomplete-alt id="idOfDiv" placeholder="" pause="400" selected-object="selectedObjectName" remote-api-handler="searchApiToCallForAutoCompleteOtions" remote-url-data-field="data" title-field="titleFieldValue" minlength="1" input-class="form-control form-control-small" initial-value="valueHoldingModel" match-class="highlight" field-required="false" input-name="anguCompleteFieldName" input-changed="anguCompleteInputChanged" ></div>
```

Going into the implementation, how it looks in JS..

```
$scope.selectedObjectName = function(selected){
if(selected){
  $scope.valueHoldingModel = selected.originalObject;
  $scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:changeInput', idOfDiv, valueDisplay); 
  //you could have set with $scope.toWhereverYouWant = $scope.valueHoldingModel (warning below)
  //All other things you want to update/do while its selected-object is created
}else{
  $scope.valueHoldingModel = null; //This is if you want to clear the "non-selected" from angucomplete option, the object.
}
```

Fair-Warning, $scope.valueHoldingModel if used to move to another model breaks right away after, not sure why I have had that experience.
What i mean: `$scope.iWantValuesHere = $scope.valueHoldingModel`

Additionally, powerful things that allow us to maintain greater control on the Angucomplete inputs is the `input-changed` attribute, which allows us to keep a function like..

```
$scope.anguCompleteInputChanged = function(str){
 console.log(str)
 if((str){
  $scope.valueHoldingModel.titleFieldValue = str; //More likely want to do.
  //and Anything else you want to do
 }else{
  $scope.valueHoldingModel = {} //This is somewhere you dont want to get, but will help fix if your object is undefined, following the first select "breaking" 
  $scope.valueHoldingModel.titleFieldValue = str;
 }
}
```

Having explained most of the running of this... this is what the remote API call for the anguComplete options drop-down for selection would be called

```
$scope.searchApiToCallForAutoCompleteOtions = function(userInputString,timeoutPromise){
        return $http.post('http://my.domain.com:80/api/domain_block/api_specific/',{search_value: userInputString,token: $rootScope.user.token},{timeout: timeoutPromise});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind it to

```
selectedobject="AddShareForm.whatever"
```

If that doesn't work, then I would add a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="whatever">
```

And then set the selected object to whatever the `ng-model` was:

```
selectedobject="whatever"
```

Comment: tried selectedobject="AddShareForm.nick", it didn't make a selection